# Draw a snap pattern on a Grid control

Tags: c#, wpf, background, grid, visualbrush

I have a solution that I use but that one is not really giving me all the abilities that I need.

Right now, I'm setting the background of my Grid control to a VisualBrush that contains an ellipse on its Visual container. This makes it impossible for me to set a background color(or at least with my knowledge until now) BEHIND the drawn squares.

I am using these squares as markers for my snap to position functionality. See pic.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9CZf.jpg

Is there a possible way for me to keep my background pattern and also be able to set a background color? Another approach are also welcome as I feel like I have snowed in on this one because it works(partially).

Due to demand:

```
  brush = new VisualBrush();
  brush.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
  brush.TileMode = TileMode.Tile;
  brush.Viewport = new Rect(0, 0, SnapDistance, SnapDistance);
  brush.ViewportUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
  brush.Viewbox = new Rect(0, 0, SnapDistance, SnapDistance);
  brush.ViewboxUnits = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
  ellipse = new Ellipse() { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), Width = 2, Height = 2 };
  brush.Visual = ellipse;
```

This is what I set to the grid.Background. What I want to do is to draw the pattern I show in the link and also be able to set a color to the background with the dot pattern on that.

Comment: Please provide your sample code with the pain points.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want the background to be something other than white? Could you post the code that you have right now?

Comment: added code for my VisualBrush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overlay the grid with Canvas with the snap points or you can create an adorner layer with the snap points.

Cite from [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737.aspx)

> Adorners are a special type of FrameworkElement, used to provide visual cues to a user. Among other uses, Adorners can be used to add functional handles to elements or provide state information about a control.

So the controls layout (in Z-order) will be:

- the grid
- the overlay with the snap points (don't know how the events will be handled then)
- your elements

or

- the grid

  - the adorner layer
- your elements

Comment: Karel, first, thanks for your reply. I will investigate and vote up your answer if I make it work.

Comment: thanks, hope it will help you (an example to enable drag&resize for UI element: http://denisvuyka.wordpress.com/2007/10/15/wpf-simple-adorner-usage-with-drag-and-resize-operations/)

Comment: Is the Adorner not working with Grid component? When I try to fetch the AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(grid); it returns null! Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you really need grid? You're not placing your elements in rows and column, right?

Comment: Yes, this is by requirement of other components in our project. Does it come with a problem? Grid and adorner?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, maybe you can get AdornerLayer for grid parent.

Comment: No worries, I fetched it! I will just grab something to eat and continue with it.

Comment: Works to print out the dotted pattern that I wanted, I just dont get how to ZIndex those now. That is another question and this is marked as solved. :)